# Real number that doesn't belong in $[c,d]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $r_{1},...,r_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $[a,b]$ with $a<b$.Then there exist $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$,with $c<d$ and $r_{i}\notin [c,d]$ for all $i=1,...,n$.

How can we prove this?? The assumption that we have to find $[c,d]$ such that the $diameter([c,d])$ has to be less than the smallest different between $r_{i}-r_{j}$ for all $j\neq i$ is the only assumption that we need in order to prove it ??

Answer (score 1):

Chop the points $r_1, r_2, \cdots r_n$ out of $[a,b]$ and you have a finite union of intervals. Now choose a closed subinterval $[c,d]$ of one of these intervals.